# Visual Studio 2010 Web Test Url property supports data binding but how to validate Expected Response URL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-testing

With a Visual Studio 2010 Web Test the Url property can be data bound to a list of URLs from a CSV file but it seems the Expected Response URL can't be data bound.  The Expected Response URL just takes a string value.  Am I missing something?

In this situation how could you test to see the URL of the page requested is actually the URL of the page you end up on and not a redirection to some other page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Expected Response Url *can* actually be data-bound -- you just have to enter the appropriate context parameter name by hand (don't forget the curly-braces).

The fact that you don't get the helpful drop-down arrow that opens the data-binding panel/list is a UI oversight/bug.

I'll report that on Connect but [dig] don't hold your breath that it'll get fixed [/dig].